# Wordpress Архив всех авторов

Tags: wordpress

Как в WP прикрепить архив всех авторов/пользователей, чтобы было, как с любым другим типом записи — Главная / Авторы / Автор. Что значит — нужно чтобы у пользователей был архив Авторы, где выводятся все пользователи, чего почему-то нету из коробки и *site*/author/admin/ — это ок, а вот *site*/author это уже 404 хотя по логике вордпресса там должен быть архив авторов, разве что в регистрации типа записи стоит has_archive => false.

Из моих мыслей это
А) Сделать шаблон страницы (Архив авторов), где будут выводится собственно авторы. Но тогда это будет не совсем то ибо клиент хочет чтобы в тех же хлебных крошках мы имели
«Главная / Авторы / Джон Сноу».
Б) Зарегистрировать тип записи Авторов и потом крутить к постам мета-боксы с выбором автора но это дичайший костыль особенно, когда у нас из коробки такой функционал есть.
Г) И наверно самое логичное — как то перезаписать параметр has_archive для типа записи author.

Или я несу чушь и до конца не знаю по какой системе в ВП работают авторы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Из моих мыслей это А) Сделать шаблон страницы (Архив авторов), где
> будут выводится собственно авторы. Но тогда это будет не совсем то ибо
> клиент хочет чтобы в тех же хлебных крошках мы имели

Мысль о создании шаблона правильная, только вот хлебные крошки не имеют никакого отношения к URL.

Чтобы по адресу `site/author/` вывести список авторов можно создать шаблон `page-author.php` и пустую страницу со слагом `author`.
В самом же шаблоне использовать [wp_list_authors](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_list_authors).

Comment: Понял, спасибо)